# How to calculate the sum of general type $\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} {2 k- n + a \choose r }$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> **QUESTION.** How to calculate the sum of such general type?
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} {2 k - n + a \choose r }. $$

Some particular examples
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a}  = {2n\choose n+a},$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} \binom{2 k - n + a}1 = 0, $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} {2 k - n + a \choose 2}  = -\frac{(a+ n)(a-n)}{2 (2n-1)} {2n\choose n+a}, $$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} {2 k - n + a \choose 3}  = \frac{(a+ n)(a-n)}{2 (2n-1)} {2n\choose n+a}. $$
I am struggling to calculate at least
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose k+a} {2 k - n + a \choose 4}   $$
Can someone  help me with this one?

Comment: Is there a typo? The factor ${2l-n+a\choose r}$ does not depend on $k$.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected this.

Answer (score 7):

The pattern continues indeed except the RHS becomes more and more involved as you increase $r$. At any rate, here is what we get for the case $r=4$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k+a}\binom{2k-n+a}4=
\frac{(a^2-n^2-6n+11)\,(a-n)\,(a+n)}{8\,(2n-1)\,(2n-3)}\cdot \binom{2n}{n+a}.$$
Another sampler for $r=5$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{n}{k+a}\binom{2k-n+a}5=
-\frac{(a^2-n^2-2n+5)\,(a-n)\,(a+n)}{4\,(2n-1)\,(2n-3)}\cdot \binom{2n}{n+a}.$$
These kinds of problems can be proved by the automated tools of [Zeilberger's algorithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeilbergersAlgorithm.html) which relies on [Wilf-Zeilberger pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair). If you are able to use the Maple symbolic software then [download the algorithm](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Ezeilberg/tokhniot/EKHAD) to make use of it. These days, this package is also part of the routines in Maple as well as Mathematica.

Comment: Thak you. What is  Zeilberger's algorithm , and where I found practical tools with it?

Comment: It may be possible to construct the recurrence?

Answer (score 5):

For fixed $r$ you may expand ${2k-n+a\choose r}$ as a polynomial in $k$ (whose coefficients are polynomials in $n-a$) as ${2k-n+a\choose r}=\sum_{i=0}^r c_i {k\choose i}$. To find $c_i$'s, fix $s\in \{0,1,\ldots,r\}$; substitute $k=j\in \{0,1,\ldots,s\}$ to get $\sum_{i=0}^j c_i{j\choose i}={2j-n+a\choose r}$, multiply this by $(-1)^{s-j}{s\choose j}$ and sum up over $j=0,\ldots,s$. Then $c_i$ comes with the coefficient $$\sum_{j=i}^s (-1)^{s-j}{j\choose i}{s\choose j}=\sum_{j=i}^s (-1)^{s-j}{s\choose i}{s-i\choose j-i}={s\choose i}\sum_{\ell=0}^{s-i}(-1)^{s-i-\ell}{s-i\choose \ell}=\delta_{is},$$
and we get $$c_s=\sum_{j=0}^s (-1)^{s-j}{s\choose j}{2j-n+a\choose r}.$$

Therefore your sum $S$ equals
$$S=\sum_{i=0}^r c_i\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}{k\choose i}{n\choose k+a}.$$ Now use $${n\choose k}{k\choose i} ={n\choose i} {n-i\choose k-i},$$
and finally apply Vandermonde convolution $$\sum_{k=i}^n {n-i\choose k-i}{n\choose k+a}={2n-i\choose n+a}$$
to express your sum as $$S=\sum_{i=0}^rc_i{n\choose i}{2n-i\choose n+a}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you specify this algorithm?

Comment: I mean a usual algorithm of expanding the polynomial in binomial basis, like Newton inrerpolation. Possibly there are more clever ways to find these $c_i$ and then to simplify the answer

Comment: OK. How can the last expression be useful? My sum includes rather 3 binomials than 2.

Comment: I added more details

Comment: Aha . Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, one can get an explicit expression for a fixed $r$ via generating functions by noticing that the given sum equals
$$[y^{n+a}z^r]\ (y+1+z)^n (1+y(1+z))^n (1+z)^{-n}$$
and rewriting it as
$$[y^{n+a}z^r]\ \big((1+y)^2 + \frac{z^2}{1+z}y\big)^n = [y^{n+a}z^r]\ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{i} (1+y)^{2(n-i)} y^i\left(\frac{z^2}{1+z}\right)^i,$$
which we evaluate as
$$[y^{n+a}]\ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor} \binom{n}i\binom{-i}{r-2i} (1+y)^{2(n-i)}y^i = (-1)^r \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}  \binom{n}i \binom{r-i-1}{r-2i} \binom{2(n-i)}{n+a-i}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(1+y)^2 +\frac{z^2}{1+z}$ in the first bracket? (You don't get $0$ for $r=1$)

Comment: @esg: Good catch! Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.